# How to implement ez-vcard-android?

Tags: android

Hi I need to implement ez-vcard-android to import a vcf file, but I do not see how to do it. Any info would be appreciate it as I could not find anything useful searching Google. Thanks

Comment: I forgot to include the link: https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard-android

Comment: Before asking a question please review what you have found. Did you look at the TestActivity at least? https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard-android/blob/master/android-mapper/src/main/java/ezvcard/android/TestActivity/VcardParser.java

Comment: I need to find out what files or jar files need to be included to my project first, I dont see any info about that. I want to implement it but I dont see how thanks.

Comment: Read https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard-android/blob/master/README.md#download

Comment: I already have my friend, and if you read it it does not tell you quack! Otherwise I would not be asking. If anyone knows what files or jar files to copy from this project to my project your answer would be appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: I would try to download and run the sample app. If it works check the build.gradle file for library dependencies - use those in your app using API.  Otherwise I would at the other git project: https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard with the understanding that the ez-vcard-android needs a jar/library of the pure Java version. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it!